# Get the recently added item in collection view

Tags: .net, wpf, collectionview

Is there a way to get the position or the item of the recently added item in CollectionView.

Reagrds,
Vikram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to the `CollectionView.CollectionChanged` event. When the event fires, look at the `Action` property of [`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.aspx), and if it's equal to `Add` the newly added items will be included inside the `NewItems` collection. Usually this will contain just one item, which you can save to an appropriate variable or class member. When you need to know what the recently added item was, read this variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Can you please provide a small code snippet as reference as I am in doubt how do we get NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs, do I need to inherit the Collection(Source of CollectioView) from INotifyCollectionChanged .

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own collection based on `CollectionView`. Inside this collection, store a map between items and time when they were added (to detect newly added items subscribe to `CollectionView.CollectionChanged` event). Define method in your collection for accessing items by time `public IEnumerable<T> GetItems(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a source collection which is inherited from `INotifyCollectionChanged`, you can use the `ObservableCollection` which implicitly inherits from INotifyCollectionChanged. And you can subscribe to the CollectionChanged event for your source then and can look at the `Action` property and `NewItems` Collection in it. Sample code -

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Names
{
    get;
    set;
}

private ICollectionView source;
public ICollectionView Source
{
   get
   {
      if (source == null)
      {
         source = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Names);
         source.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(source_CollectionChanged);
      }
      return source;
    }
}

void source_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
   {
      // Can play with e.NewItems here.
   }
}
```